# How to add a Before() function in Cypress Feature Files?

Tags: cucumber, cypress, feature-file

I am using feature files in my Cypress framework.

Below is an example of a scenario:

```
Scenario: #1 Cancel should return to Customer Management landing page
 Given User is on the Edit Customer Page
 When User updates the email address to "abc@gmail.com"
 Then the updated email address will appear on the summary page
```

The problem I'm facing is that when I re-run this test, the original email address will be **"abc@gmail.com"** *(the value it was updated to during the first test run)*. So the test won't actually *update* the email address.

What is the best approach to deal with this issue?

I was thinking of using something like a `Before()` function to delete the customer if it exists, & re-create it. Then I'd be able to update it & the values will be the same each time.

However, I don't know how to add a `Before()` in a feature file. I have a `Background` that navigates to a certain page, but is that the place where I should be putting it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [cypress-cucumber-preprocessor](https://github.com/TheBrainFamily/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor#before-and-after-hooks) supports both Mocha's before/beforeEach/after/afterEach hooks and Cucumber's Before and After hooks. So in your step Definition file, you can:

```js
//This example is with the Cucumber hooks
const {
  Before,
  After,
  Given,
  Then,
} = require('cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/steps')

// this will get called before each scenario
Before(() => {
  //Code to delete customer if it exists
})
```

Answer (score 5):

TheBrainFamily recommend using **Given**

Please see [Step definitions](https://github.com/TheBrainFamily/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor#step-definitions)

> This is a good place to put before/**beforeEach**/after/afterEach hooks related to that particular feature. This is incredibly hard to get right with pure cucumber.

So

- Add codition to Given
- Use beforeEach()

```js
import { Given } from "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/steps";

const url = 'https://google.com'
Given('User is on the Edit Customer Page And Email is empty', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    // reset email
  })
  ...
})
```